# How to set onLongPress for a particular relative layout using GestureDetectorCompat?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

In my code, onLongPress works in full screen but I need onLongPress into particular relative layout.After getting X and Y values in LongPress, I have to perform some actions in onLongPress event.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;
public Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new MyGestureListener());
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myView);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void message(Context ctx,String msg,int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, duration).show();
}

private class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        message(getBaseContext()," X value is " + x + " Y value is "+ y ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        super.onLongPress(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        message(getBaseContext(),"Single tab" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: so feed your detector with that layout's MotionEvent

Comment: nope,  instead read about MotionEvent handling in a View: guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Answer (score 0):

try this with handler in action down event

```
imgMainNotification.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    { 
                        public void run()
                        {

                            //do what youwanna do on long press here 

                        }
                    }, 1 * 3000);

                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Handler will post a work for given time period. It's not a long press.

Comment: if you want long press on touch event you must to use handler,